Azuredevops migration to Gitlab/Github
I am looking for migrating Azure devops source code to Gitlab. I am aware of mirror concept but this is not syncing Pull Request/Merge Request history. Is there a script or tool available ?
Migrate all source including merge history records to Gitlab.

I noticed that your title is Azure DevOps migration to Gitlab/Github, but in the subsequent questions only Gitlab is mentioned.
I investigated the documentation related to GitLab and found that currently there isn’t a direct built-in tool or script specifically for migrating from Azure DevOps to GitLab with full merge history.
But you can refer to the following workaround：

Perform a migration from Azure DevOps to GitHub.


You can import a repository with GitHub Importer, or migrate from Azure DevOps to GitHub with GitHub Enterprise Importer. You can check the detailed steps from the above document link.


Then perform a migration from GitHub to Gitlab.


Refer the steps in this GitLab document to  import your GitHub repository into GitLab.

